# How can I get D averages from a HxWxD tensor

Tags: deep-learning, max-pooling, deeplearn.js

How can I create a graph element in Deeplearnjs which turns my [h, w, d] shape tensor in to one which is [d] shape where each is the max of that layer.  If h and w are the same, this can be done with the maxpool function.  If like the same for mean.  Mean can be achieved using conv2d, but only if w and h are equal.

I need this in a graph so I can apply training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `dl.mean(your_tensor, [0, 1])` or `your_tensor.mean([0, 1])` to get the mean along the h and w dimensions. Either one will return a tensor with shape [d]. This also works in training because deeplearnjs has moved to an eager execution mode and a gradient is defined in the [mean reduction op](https://github.com/PAIR-code/deeplearnjs/blob/cf1bf6018b8c08ee3579f4073efa39914cbe5e8c/src/ops/reduction_ops.ts#L169). You can see the [mnist_eager](https://github.com/PAIR-code/deeplearnjs/tree/42d1fe186a4b91edae2b14c3d9bb4785c862a3c4/demos/mnist_eager) demo for an example of training without a Graph.